# Accessing the normalized tokens of an ElasticSearch document

Tags: elasticsearch, solr

I'm using the standard English analyzer on text fields in my ElasticSearch docs.

I'm interested in accessing the list of *normalized* terms, so if the text is `"Set the shape to semi-transparent by calling set_trans(5)"` I want to access the normalized tokens `set, shape, semi, transpar, call, set_tran, 5`.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the termsvector endpoint for this:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Analyze API, you can ask any string and get the tokens extracted from it.
Example from the [Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html)

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_analyze' -d '
{
  "tokenizer" : "keyword",
  "filters" : ["lowercase"],
  "text" : "this is a test"
}'

curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_analyze' -d '
{
  "tokenizer" : "keyword",
  "token_filters" : ["lowercase"],
  "char_filters" : ["html_strip"],
  "text" : "this is a <b>test</b>"
}'
```